# Error on ajv dependency when trying to build my application

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajv

I run into this error when trying to build my app on the `ajv` dependency

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
✖ Compilation failed with errors
\node_modules\ajv\lib\refs\data.json: Missing semicolon. (2:13)
  1 | {
> 2 |     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    |              ^
  3 |     "$id": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajv-validator/ajv/master/lib/refs/data.json#",
  4 |     "description": "Meta-schema for $data reference (JSON Schema extension proposal)",
  5 |     "type": "object",
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

I have tried using yarn or npm still same issue. Also tried using older versions of ajv and still run into same issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is as much code as is displayed in the terminal